# When to use Regex.prototype symbol method?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, ecmascript-6, symbols

We can use Regex constructor for dynamic input and use regex literal for other cases. But when should one use Regex prototype symbol method?

Example from [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@search):

```
class RegExp1 extends RegExp {
  constructor(str) {
    super(str);
    this.pattern = str;
  }
  [Symbol.search](str) {
    return str.indexOf(this.pattern);
  }
}

console.log('table football'.search(new RegExp1('foo')));
// expected output: 6
```

Anyone has used `[@@Symbol]` for regex, a practical need use case would be better to know.

Comment: _"But when should one use Regex prototype symbol method?"_ - Never, unless you want to have a custom object that extends the regular `RegExp` one with custom behavior like in your example.

Comment: `console.log('table football'.search(new RegExp('foo')));` will do the same. I would be glad to know practical example of custom behavior that normally we can't do.

Comment: Your question already has _"custom behavior"_ defined for `.search()` o.O

Answer (score 1):

The dependency on RegExp is loose (see for instance the ECMA Script specification on [`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-string.prototype.matchall) and [IsRegExp](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-isregexp)):

1. The object passed to the methods `search`, `match`, `replace` and `split` of `String.prototype` does not *have* to be a `RegExp` (inherited) instance. It is enough that the object implements the corresponding Symbol method (e.g. `@@search`) to have your custom implementation used. There is no `RegExp` related requirement.
2. There is one exception to the above rule when it concerns `String.prototype.matchAll`. Then there is a specific requirement that loosely relates to `RegExp`:

   If your object has a `@@match` property that is truthy or the object is an instance of `RegExp` (has a `[[RegExpMatcher]]` internal slot), then the object must have a `flags` property whose string representation includes the character "g".

   This practically means that if your object did not inherit from `RegExp.prototype`, and implements `@@match`, it also needs a `flags` property as otherwise calling `String.prototype.matchAll` will always throw a TypeError.

### Practical Uses

Defining these Symbol methods could be useful when you have an alternative to the standard RegExp behaviour.

Here are some ideas/examples:

- A `Pattern` class that understands simple patterns like "AAA-999". The implementation could easily translate the pattern to a regex;
- A `Like` class that understands patterns as used with the `LIKE` operator in SQL, such as "%abc%def%" or "answer_". The implementation could easily translate such a pattern to a regex;
- A `RegExpImm` class whose instances are *immutable*. One of the sometimes surprising behaviours of `RegExp` instances is that they have state and running a method like `test` twice in a row on the same `RegExp` instance can give different outputs. You could decide you want a flavour of `RegExp` that is immutable and does not have such side effects.
- A `RegExpEx` class that can execute **recursive** regular expressions (which at the time of writing are not natively supported in JavaScript), so that you could for instance do:

  ```
  "(()()(()))()".replace(new RegExpEx(String.raw`(?:\((?R)\))*`), "") == ""
  ```
- A `CssPattern` class that can find substrings in an HTML string, using a CSS selector (which would obviously rely on `DOMParser`), so that you could for instance do:

  ```
  "<div><p class='x'>hello</p></div>".match(new CssPattern("p")) 
       === "<p class='x'>hello</p>"
  ```
- A `Bnf` class that can find strings that fulfill a BNF specification. BNF may be easier to read and design than a regular expression. Also, they can be recursive. See example below.

...so anything that could serve to find substrings in a string based on some algorithm that is (slightly) different than the native regex implementation. When you have such a class, then it would be nice that you can pass an instance of that class to the relevant `String.prototype` methods, and that is why it could be interesting to implement one or more of these Symbol methods in your class.

### Example implementation

I took one of the above ideas to create an implementation: a class for creating objects from a simplified BNF-like specification. Some characteristics:

- Does not inherit from `RegExp`
- Does not implement a notion of "capture groups" or flags other than "g"
- Instances are (intended as) immutable
- Match objects returned by `@@matchAll` or `@@match` (when not global) have a different format than usual: `{ input: string, match: string, span: [number, number] }`
- The BNF input should be an object with its rules subdivided into two categories: `sequences` and `choices`. Both will define grammar rules as string arrays. Such string can either be the name of another rule or (when no such match is found) be literals to match. A sequence matches when all its array elements match one after the other. A choice matches when one of its array elements matches.
- The implementation is not optimised, nor thoroughly tested. This just serves as an example of how it could be used to some benefit.

```js
class Bnf {
    #rules
    #start
    #flags
    
    constructor(bnf, rule, flags="") {
        this.#flags = flags;
        this.#rules = Object.assign({}, 
            Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(bnf.sequences).map(([name, rule]) =>
                [name, Object.assign([], rule, { isChoice: false })]
            )),
            Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(bnf.choices).map(([name, rule]) =>
                [name, Object.assign([], rule, { isChoice: true })]
            ))
        );
        this.#start = rule;
    }
    get flags()  { return this.#flags }
    get global() { return this.#flags.includes("g") }
    toString() {
        return Object.entries(this.#rules).map(([name, rule]) =>
            `<${name}> ::= ${rule.map(name => 
                this.#rules[name] ? `<${name}>` : JSON.stringify(name)
            ).join(rule.isChoice ? ' | ' : ' ')}`
        ).join("\n");
    }        
    #parse(s, i, rule=[this.#start], nameSet=[]) {
        if (rule.length == 0) return i;
        const [name, ...after] = rule;
        if (nameSet.includes(name)) return -1; // cycle
        rule = this.#rules[name];
        if (!rule) { // Literal
            if (s.slice(i, i + name.length) !== name) {
                return -1;
            }
            i += name.length;
            return this.#parse(s, i, after, []); 
        }
        if (rule.isChoice) { // Choices
            rule = rule.map(choice => [choice, ...after]);
            for (const seq of rule) {
                const j = this.#parse(s, i, seq, nameSet);
                if (j > -1) return j;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        return this.#parse(s, i, rule.concat(after), nameSet.concat(name));
    }
    #nextMatch(input, i=0) {
        for (let index = i; index < input.length; index++) {
            let end = this.#parse(input, index);
            if (end > -1) return { input, match: s.slice(index, end), span: [index, end] };
        }
        return null;
    }
    test(str) {
        return !!this.#nextMatch(str, 0);
    }
    [Symbol.search](str) {
        return this.#nextMatch(str, 0)?.span?.[0];
    }
    *[Symbol.matchAll](str) {
        for (let match = { span: [0, 0] }; match = this.#nextMatch(str, match.span[1]); null) yield match;
    }
    [Symbol.match](str) {
        return this.global ? Array.from(this[Symbol.matchAll](str), m => m.match) : this.#nextMatch(str);
    }
    [Symbol.split](str, limit=Infinity) {
        const result = [];
        if (limit <= 0) return result;
        let last = 0;
        for (const match of this[Symbol.matchAll](str)) {
            result.push(str.slice(last, match.span[0]));
            if (result.length >= limit) return result;
            last = match.span[1];
        }
        return result.concat(str.slice(last));
    }
    [Symbol.replace](str, replacement) {
        const result = [];
        let last = 0;
        for (const match of this[Symbol.matchAll](str)) {
            result.push(str.slice(last, match.span[0]),
                        (typeof replacement === "function" ? replacement(match.match, match.span[0], str) : replacement)); 
            last = match.span[1];
            if (!this.global) break;
        }
        return result.concat(str.slice(last)).join("");
    }
}

// Demo
const bnfSpec = {
    sequences: {
        multidigit:       ["digit", "unsigned"],
        negation:         ["-", "spaces", "factor"],
        nestedexpression: ["(", "spaces", "expression", "spaces", ")"],
        multiplication:   ["factor", "spaces", "operator2", "spaces", "term"],
        addition:         ["term", "spaces", "operator1", "spaces", "expression"],
        multispace:       [" ", "spaces"],
    },
    choices: {
        digit:      [..."0123456789"],
        operator2:  [..."*\/"],
        operator1:  [..."+-"],
        spaces:     ["multispace", ""],
        unsigned:   ["multidigit", "digit"],
        factor:     ["negation", "nestedexpression", "unsigned"],
        term:       ["multiplication", "factor"],
        expression: ["addition", "term"],
    }
};

const bnf = new Bnf(bnfSpec, "expression", "g");
console.log(bnf.toString()); // pretty print the BNF
const s = "This -123 and (9 - (5 + 1)) * 8 are valid, and 3+ (1+ 2)* 9) has a closing parenthesis too many";
console.log(s.search(bnf)); // 5
console.log(s.match(bnf)); // ['-123', '(9 - (5 + 1)) * 8', '3+ (1+ 2)* 9']
console.log(s.split(bnf, 2)); // ['This ', ' and ']
console.log(s.replace(bnf, m => `[${m}]`)); // This [-123] and [(9 - (5 + 1)) * 8] are valid, and [3+ (1+ 2)* 9]) has a closing parenthesis too many
console.log(...s.matchAll(bnf)); // (3 match objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the example demonstrates, you implement [a `[Symbol.search]` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/search) on pattern objects that you want to use in the [string `search` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search). This lets you hook into the native string method. Put differently, [ES6 introduced](https://2ality.com/2015/09/well-known-symbols-es6.html) a form of [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) via the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) so that the argument decides which search algorithm to use.

Notice you don't have to subclass `RegExp` for this to be useful:

```js
class Pattern {
  constructor(str) {
    this.value = str;
  }
  [Symbol.search](str) {
    return str.indexOf(this.value);
  }
}

console.log('table football'.search(new Pattern('foo')));
```