# JavaScript recursive/circular regexps

Tags: javascript, regex, antlr4

I have an ANTLR4 grammar file and there is a pair of circularly-dependent rules, if you can call them that. Here are those rules:

```
call
    : ID LPAREN (expr (COMMA expr)*)? RPAREN 
    ;

expr
    : operand
    | call
    | NOT expr
    | expr (AND|OR|ADD|SUB|MUL|DIV) expr
    | expr LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
    ;
```

`call` references `expr`, and `expr` references `call`. What I'm looking for is a way to implement such string checks using JavaScript RegExp. It would also help to have some sort of recursive RegExp for the `expr` rule, but something tells me that whatever could solve the circular dependency issue would solve the recursion issue as well. If it exists, that is :)

I tried:

- Using (?R)? in the regexp, but JavaScript's RegExps don't seem to have this functionality
- Using XRegExp.matchRecursive, but, judging by the API description and by what I got then playing around with it, it is not exactly what I'm looking for
- Creating my own custom RecursiveRegExp class with an overridden constructor and exec() method, but it appears that I'm not skilled in JS enough to pull off something like this :)

Is there a way to, perhaps, insert a "link" to another RegExp into a RegExp literal, or something like that?

Comment: you cannot (and shouldn't) parse a general context-free language with regexes. If you're already using ANTLR, why don't you just let it generate a parser for you?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75069466/5459839)?

Comment: What is `operand`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm looking for is a way to implement such string checks using JavaScript RegExp.

That is not possible.

What you *can* do is use the [ANTLR grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr/antlr4) that defines ANTLR itself and generate JavaScript parser. That parser can then be used to parse the grammar containing the `call` and `expr` rules. The resulting parse tree can then be used to discover which rule references what other rule(s).